# Dynamic generation of CheckBox in asp.net gridview does not maintain the state

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

aspx code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="TestButton" runat="server" OnClick="TestButton_Click"
            Text="AddNewRow" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" GridLines="Both"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="MyGrid_DataBound"
            EnableViewState="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CheckBox1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" EnableViewState="true"
                           runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CheckBox2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server"
                           EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CheckBox3">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server"
                           AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```
public DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
protected void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataRow dr = null;
   if(ViewState["T"]==null)
   {
      Dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
      Dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CheckBox1", typeof(bool)));
      Dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CheckBox2", typeof(bool)));
      Dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CheckBox3", typeof(bool)));
      ViewState["T"] = Dt;
    }
    Dt =(DataTable) ViewState["T"];
    dr = Dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = "Sam";
    dr["CheckBox1"] = true;
    dr["CheckBox2"] = false;
    dr["CheckBox3"] = false;
    Dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    SearchGrid.DataSource = Dt;
    SearchGrid.DataBind();
 }
 protected void MyGrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    (SearchGrid.Rows[SearchGrid.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].FindControl("CheckBox1")
                as CheckBox).Checked = true;
  }
}
```

when i click the the Addnew row button the result would be some thing like this

[image]

but when i click again

[image]

the first row check box gets uncheckd. i have enabled the view state for each checkbox 
but still it does not work. is tehre some thing i should do with the data table which i am binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewState is perfectly fine. It must be storing the data you want to persist.

You haven't bound your gridView Columns to any field, in this case the DataColumn names of your DataTable.
Bind your checkboxes like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxX" runat="sever" 
           Checked ='<%# Eval("DataFieldName") %>' />
```

i.e.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CheckBox1") %>' 
      AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" />

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CheckBox2") %>' 
  AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" />

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CheckBox3") %>' 
  AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" />
```

since CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3 are the field(column) names of the `DataSource` assigned to the `SearchGrid(GridView)`